# Using GIMP, how do I fill the canvas with an image?

Tags: gimp

I have this in my canvas:
[image]

What I want to do is cover the whole canvas with this image; the image is 250 px wide, so I want to add 3 more so the whole canvas looks like fire!

How do I do that?  (I've read the GIMP book, looked on SO and Google, but found nothing...)

Answer (score 10):

Select and copy the image to put it on your clipboard, then use the bucket fill tool with the pattern option, selecting the clipboard pattern. If you want to keep the image around for further use, you can always save it as a pattern.

Comment: Hi Stan... got it... needed a layer... :D  thank you for your help...

Comment: You do not need to use the bucket fill tool, btw - drag and drop the layer from the layers dialog (note: that is different from the patterns popup of the tool) to the image, and the active layer or selection will be filled. Layers dialog docs: http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-pattern-dialog.html

Comment: *use the bucket fill tool with the pattern option, selecting the clipboard pattern* -there is nothig like this

Comment: Agree with @JonZon when I pick pattern fill it just gives me some preset patterns as options, I don't see a clipboard option.

Answer (score 0):

I am a very desultory GIMP user. Each time I find myself having to learn again the most basic ropes.

In my case, I came here because I needed to widen a picture by resizing its canvas and repeating central pieces in the sides.

[image: very poor result, I admit...]

I could not obtain anything from the buckets & patterns mentioned in the first answer, so I just went on with:

1. activate the rectangle selector tool and select the part I want to copy
2. click Edit -> Copy Visible in the menu
3. again with the rectangle selector tool, select a piece of the unfilled area
4. click Edit -> Paste Into in the menu
5. position the colored chunk precisely and hit Esc repeatedly

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, Marco, are you aware of [seam carving](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/124408/resize-part-of-image-in-gimp/124411#124411)? It could be useful for your specific example.

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design! If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: @PaoloGibellini - wow!!! that's exactly what I need... thank you!